# Deprecated org.apache.xmlbeans.xml.stream.XMLInputStream

Tags: java, xmlbeans

I'm trying to run this project: `https://github.com/sebkur/gradle-xmlbeans-plugin/tree/master/test-local/test2`

But with latest Gradle dependency `implementation 'org.apache.xmlbeans:xmlbeans:5.0.3'`

I get generated this deprecated and missing code:

```
/** @deprecated {@link org.apache.xmlbeans.xml.stream.XMLInputStream} */
public static com.optimalpayments.creditcard.xmlschema.v1.CcAuthenticateRequestV1Document parse(org.apache.xmlbeans.xml.stream.XMLInputStream xis, org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlOptions options) throws org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlException, org.apache.xmlbeans.xml.stream.XMLStreamException {
  return (com.optimalpayments.creditcard.xmlschema.v1.CcAuthenticateRequestV1Document) org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlBeans.getContextTypeLoader().parse( xis, type, options ); }
```

I get `Cannot resolve symbol 'XMLInputStream'` Do you know how I can fix this?

Comment: https://github.com/sebkur/gradle-xmlbeans-plugin/blob/master/build.gradle seems to use XMLBeans 3.1.0. If you want to use XMLBeans 5, maybe you should contact the project maintainer to update their setup. There is a Maven Plugin that is maintained by the Apache XMLBeans team - https://xmlbeans.apache.org/guide/Maven.html